# Enable ClangdSwitchSourceHeader to work with separate source and header files

Tags: neovim, liskov-substitution-principle, clangd

I'm trying to set up my Neovim/LSP/Clangd setup at work. We use two different ways to store source (`.cpp`). and header (`.h`) files. The first way is the common approach, where both the source and header files are placed in the same folder. The second way involves keeping the source files in the `lib` folder and the headers in the `include` folder. Additionally, all header files are symlinked in a single folder called `all_includes`.

The LSP suggestions work perfectly with the example `.clangd` configuration provided below:

```
CompileFlags:
Add: [-I../include,
      -I/path/to/folder/with/all/includes/all_includes]
```

However, the feature of switching between source and header with `ClangdSwitchSourceHeader` only works in the first approach or from source to header.

Does Clangd have an option to locate the source file in this case? I know that the source file for it is located at the path `../lib`. Is there an option to provide this information to Clang, or is there an easier solution that involves creating my own Lua function to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project is indexed (this requires a `compile_commands.json` file, see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup), clangd should generally be able to figure out the matching source/header file based on their contents (e.g. the source file is the file containing the definitions of the functions declared in the header file, that sort of thing).

A filename-based heuristic that works with the source and header files being in different directories is not currently implemented, but that would be useful; there is https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1617 open for it.